# Latex: How do I make my second table column span multiple rows

Tags: latex

I have seen tutorials on how to set a column span multiple rows but that's only for the first column.

```
elem1  & None\\\hline
elem2  & None\\\hline
elem3  & None \\\hline
elem4  &None \\\hline
elem5  &None \\\hline
elem6  &None \\\hline
```

I would like the phrase "None" to span all the rows.

Many thanks, sorry I'm a novice!

Answer (score 3):

Taken from [wikibooks](https://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX-W%C3%B6rterbuch:_multicolumn):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\newlength{\width}
\width25mm
\begin{tabular}{|p{\width}|p{\width}|p{\width}|p{\width}|}
  \hline
  Feld & Feld & Feld & Feld \\
  \hline
  Feld&Feld&\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{two cols}\\
  \hline
  Feld&\multirow{2}{\width}{two rows}&\multicolumn{2}{|p{3cm}|}{\multirow{2}    {5cm}{two rows, two cols}}\\
  \cline{0-0}
  Feld&&\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{}\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

produces:

[image]

Since I don't like the standard layout of tables I use the following code. 
(There are some different formatting included. Of course you wouldn't use it like that.)
You can insert multicols and multirows from the first example.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{booktabs} % \cmidrule in tables
% \usepackage{caption}  % Nice Captions
% \usepackage{longtable} % Tables larger than one page
% \usepackage{multirow} % Mergings Cells
% \usepackage{multicol} % Merging Cells
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \caption{Some caption, for tables always above}
  \label{Tab:some_label}
  \begin{tabularx}{0.99\textwidth}{>{\centering}X>{\raggedleft}X>    {\raggedleft}X>{\raggedleft}p{0.5cm}>{\raggedleft}p{3cm}>{\raggedright}X>    {\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
    \toprule
    \textsc{Foobar} & $a$ & $b$ & $c$ & $d$ & $e$ & $f$ \\
    \cmidrule(r){1-1} \cmidrule(lr){2-2} \cmidrule(lr){3-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-    4} \cmidrule(lr){5-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-6} \cmidrule(l){7-7}
    1               & 2   & 2   & 2   & 2   & 2   & 2   \\
    2               & 4   & 5   & 4   & 4   & 4   & 4   \\
    3               & 4   & 3   & 4   & 3   & 3   & 3   \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\newpage
\end{document}
```

[image]